# What is ntree mean in the randomForst model in R?

Tags: r, model, random-forest, decision-tree

I am confused with value of ntree in RandonForest model. If I only have one test condition like sex, which is a categorical takes value of 0 or 1. What is the meaning of the ntree in the model? How is it possible to have the number of tress defind by ntree?  I have set ntree = 1000, ntree = 1 and ntree=3 for exmaple. the results seems

```
model<- randomForest(Survived ~ Sex, data = trainData, importance=TRUE, ntree = 1)
importance(model)
```

---

I set ntree = 1: and get

```
        0     1 MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
Sex 0.191 0.254                0.218               91
```

ntree = 2:

```
        0     1 MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
Sex 0.252 0.327                0.285             85.7
```

ntree = 3

```
        0    1 MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
Sex 27.7 15.5                 27.5             81.7
```

ntree = 500

```
 0   1 MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
Sex 137 140                  145             89.4
```

What is the results mean?
I want know:

1. The relationship between the number of test conditions with the set up of ntree numbers.
2. ntree numbers with the computation needed

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Ntree = number of trees used in aggregation. Given you only have one variable, it will always used for all trees. However, using Random Forest will also bootstrap resample subsets of the original dataset for each tree. So there is still some randomisation, which may help model non-linear relationships. Hence your results with the increased ntrees improves the mean decrease values because using a single tree is volatile depending on the sample.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So you mean even I have only one test condition like sex==male? the decision is the dame but the data used in each tree to train the model are still different. like different 70% from the train dataset?

Comment: The default setting is to sample with replacement, so even if each tree uses n observations there will be variation.